# moddle con inicion de sesion biometrico [huella dactilar]

Tags: login, moodle

¿como puedo hacer para iniciar sesión en moodle usando lector de huellas dactilares?
por ejemplo asi: [moodle con huella dactilar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddkFG9ncUyA)

gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: El lector de huellas, si no me equivoco, devuelve un hash de la huella, así que solo tienes que guardarlo en la base de datos para luego comprobar hashes, el problema es que tendrás que hacer un módulo custom o intentar buscar uno ya hecho. Aquí tienes ayuda: https://www.phpcentral.com/pregunta/30/como-implementar-lector-de-huella-que-funcione-con-html-php-y-mysql

Comment: Podrias usar los plugins propios de moodle como :https://docs.moodle.org/dev/BioAuth_Plugin